# Javascript: object has no method

Tags: javascript

I get the following error for some javascript that is to autosave a form.

Uncaught TypeError. Object [object object] has no method 'autosave'

In the header I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.autosave.js"></script>
```

and I have all the correct jquery files in the header as well.
In the body this is the part that gives the error

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("input,select,textarea").autosave({
        url: "autosave2.php",//set the php file that updates the database
        method: "post",
        grouped: true,//send data for all fields with the autosave
               success: function(data) {//on a successful update...
            $("#message").html("Data updated successfully").show();//...show a message...
            setTimeout('fadeMessage()',1500);//...and then fade it out after an interval
        },
        send: function(){//on a save...
            $("#message").html("Sending data....");//..show a message
        },
        dataType: "html"
    }); 
});

function fadeMessage(){
$('#message').fadeOut('slow');//just a function to fade out the message
}



</script>
```

Of note, if I manually submit the form, it works so I know that the autosave2.php file works.

In response to comments about jquery, the autosave.js file does appear after jquery in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.autosave.js"></script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="../js/CalendarPopup.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var cal = new CalendarPopup();
</SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/formvalidator.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is what is in autosave.js:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.autoSave = function(callback, ms) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var timer = 0, 
                $this = $(this),
                delay = ms || 1000;
            $this.keyup(function() {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                var $context = $this.val();
                if(localStorage) {
                    localStorage.setItem("autoSave", $context);
                }
                timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    callback();
                }, delay);
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: clearly you don't have a autosave method, so either the script isn't loading, or it's loading in the wrong place, as in before jQuery etc.

Comment: seems to be conflict with jQuery.

Comment: Look in your browser console for the relevant error. Probably that file you think you're importing isn't being found.

Comment: just like @Pointy said , it could be a path issue. can you tell us how your folder structure is as well? it could give an insight as to whether you are including the scripts properly or not

Comment: In terms of the paths.  when I right click and view source, I can click on all the files int he header (autosave, jequery etc) and it goes to that file and displays the JS text, so I think the paths are correct.

Comment: don't use caps for html tags and attributes.  also why have two different conventions (type / LANGUAGE)?

Comment: to pointy: error occurs at this line: $("input,select,textarea").autosave({
To hogan, legacy reasons from previous pages I have created over the years.  I don't think that is related to this error though is it?

Comment: It doesn't have the method 'autosave' because your plugin method is 'autoSave' (capital 'S').